# first N row of each id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

I have a table for my users scores like this:

```
id | kills
----------
2  | 1
1  | 1
1  | 5
1  | 3
2  | 4
2  | 5
3  | 5
```

I want to get the first 2 rows of each player which have more than 2 kills. So the result should look like this

```
id | kills
----------
1  | 5
1  | 3
2  | 4
2  | 5
3  | 5
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_stats us 
WHERE 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM user_stats f 
    WHERE f.id=us.id AND f.kills > 2
) <= 2;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first two rows"?  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so you need a column to specify the ordering.  What column is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you just want the two largest values for users that have kills > 2.  If so, use variables:

```
select us.*
from (select us.*,
             (@rn := if(@i = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@i := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from user_stats us cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @i := -1) params
      where us.kills > 2
      order by us.id, kills desc
     ) us
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: I tried to modify your code to only get rows between 2 timestamps but it doesnt work. It returns more than the limit number can you check it please: `select us.* from (select us.*, (@rn := if(@i = us.user_id, @rn + 1, if(@i := us.user_id, 1, 1) ) ) as seqnum from user_stats us,tourn_user tu cross join (select @rn := 0, @i := -1) params where (us.start_t+us.duration)<= 9999999999999 AND us.start_t >= 0 order by us.user_id, start_t ASC ) us where seqnum <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user_stats
where (id,kills) in (select id, max(kills) from user_stats where kills > 2 group by id
                    union
                    select id, min(kills) from user_stats where kills > 2 group by id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I am coming from Oracle, where rownum is a count of rows selected.  This should have the same effect.

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1, us.*
from user_stats us , (select @rownum := 0) r
where id in (
    select id from user_stats f 
    group by id 
    having count(*) > 2
)
and @rownum < 3;
```

Comment: this is wrong you limiting the total result not each group

Answer (score 0):

based on response of vkp. Take min and max when id has more then 1 kill

```
select id, max(kills) 
  from user_stats 
  group by id 
  having count(kills) > 2 
union 
select id, min(kills) 
  from user_stats 
  group by id 
  having count(kills) > 2 
order by id
```

Comment: @HiradRoshandel  *2 rows of each player which have more than 2 kills* - it should not